# How does 甘く work in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

> お汁粉は、**甘く{あまく}**煮た小豆の汁に餅などを入れた温かい食べ物です。
>   Oshiruko is a hot food with a rice cake in a *sweetly* boiled adzuki bean broth.

I think I must be misunderstanding how 甘く is used here, since you can't boil something in a sweet way.

Comment: I may be being dense, but might the thinking behind the question be like this?: "Boiling merely turns the beans soft and suitable for eating, and should have little or nothing to do with the sweetening, but the expression "甘く煮る" seems to say otherwise. Hmm..."

Comment: 逆に日本人は "paint the wall red" や "wipe tables clean" のような英語の表現に戸惑ったりしますね…（今でもすごく苦手）

Comment: @goldbrick You have understood my question well. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Earlier I explained that "煮る = boil", but upon further reflection I think I should have said  "煮る = stew". This might make addition of sugar (and other seasonings) often involved in 甘く煮る-ing more easy digest.  (A better translation for "boil" would be "茹でる")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's 結果構文 (Resultative Construction). The continuative form of an adjective (甘く here) represents the resultant state caused by the action (煮る). So 甘く煮る means "to boil/cook/stew and make sweet" (≂ 煮て甘くする), or "to boil/cook/stew in such a way that it will become sweet, by adding sugar" (≂ (砂糖で)甘くなるように煮る), i.e. "boil with sugar".

Like in this phrase, I think 煮る can include the process of flavoring -- you 煮る the ingredient in flavored water when you make [煮豆]{にまめ}, [煮魚]{にざかな}, シチュー etc. where the food is usually served with the flavored water. When you boil the food in unflavored water and drain it, like when you boil 卵, [蕎麦]{そば}, パスタ, vegetables for お[浸]{ひた}し etc, you use the verb [茹]{ゆ}でる.

cf: 「魚を[甘辛]{あまから}く[煮付]{につ}ける」
"boil/simmer fish in a way that it will be sweet and salty"
→ "boil/simmer fish with soy sauce and sugar".

A few more examples of 結果構文:

> [壁]{かべ}を[白]{しろ}く[塗]{ぬ}る (≂ 壁を塗って白くする) -- paint a wall white
>   [部屋]{へや}をきれいに[掃除]{そうじ}する (≂ 部屋を掃除してきれいにする) -- sweep a room clean
>   ご[飯]{はん}をおいしく[炊]{た}く -- make good boiled rice
>   [靴]{くつ}をピカピカに[磨]{みが}く -- polish/shine shoes well
>   [髪]{かみ}を[短]{みじか}く[切]{き}る -- cut one's hair short
>   [息子]{むすこ}を[立派]{りっぱ}に[育]{そだ}てる -- bring up one's son to be a fine/respectable man

Comment: I see. So the act of boiling makes it sweet. I hadn't understood that. I had assumed that the sweetening was separate to the boiling. Thanks.

Comment: @user3856370  I meant to say 甘く煮る means/implies "boil in such a way that the food will be sweet, by adding sugar" -> "boil with sugar." cf: 「魚を甘辛く煮付ける」 usually means "boil/simmer fish with soy sauce and sugar". Sorry if I was misreading your question...

Answer (score 3):

「甘｛あま｝く煮｛に｝た小豆｛あずき｝の汁｛しる｝」⇔「煮て甘くする」
「壁｛かべ｝を白｛しろ｝く塗｛ぬ｝る」⇔「壁を塗って白くする」
「部屋｛へや｝をきれいに掃除｛そうじ｝する」⇔「部屋を掃除してきれいにする」
「ご飯｛はん｝をおいしく炊｛たく｝く」⇔「ご飯を炊いておいしくする」
基本的｛きほんてき｝にChocolateさんの回答｛かいとう｝は合｛あ｝っていると思｛おも｝います（+1 upvote）

しかし、質問者｛しつもんしゃ｝やgoldbrickさんが素朴｛そぼく｝に疑問｛ぎもん｝を感｛かん｝じているように「煮ただけで甘くなるのか？」「壁を塗っただけで白くなるのか？」「ご飯を炊いただけでおいしくなるのか？」という疑問｛ぎもん｝が残｛のこ｝ります。また、意味｛いみ｝を理解｛りかい｝するために語順｛ごじゅん｝が大｛おお｝きく変｛か｝わるのも何｛なん｝だかすっきりしないと感｛かん｝じていることだと思｛おも｝います。

Rohan 露伴さんの回答｛かいとう｝にある「甘く煮る means boil and sweeten with sugar」や、Chocolateさんの回答の中にある "boil with sugar" が基本的に正｛ただ｝しい理解だと思います。（+1 upvote）

私は、Rohan 露伴さんの解釈｛かいしゃく｝方法｛ほうほう｝に加｛くわ｝えて次｛つぎ｝のように理解しています。

- 「甘く煮た小豆の汁」⇔「甘く（なるように砂糖｛さとう｝や味醂｛みりん｝などの甘味料｛かんみりょう｝を適切｛てきせつ｝な量｛りょう｝ 入｛い｝れて、更｛さら｝に火加減｛ひかげん｝を良｛よ｝く見｛み｝て丁寧｛ていねい｝に）煮た小豆の汁」の括弧｛かっこ｝の中｛なか｝が隠｛かく｝された表現｛ひょうげん｝です。
- 「壁を白く塗る」⇔「白く（なるように白い塗料｛とりょう｝で丁寧に）壁を塗る」
- 「ご飯をおいしく炊く」⇔「ご飯がおいしく（でき上｛あが｝るように米｛こめ｝を良｛よ｝く研｛と｝いで水｛みず｝の分量｛ぶんりょう｝を正｛ただ｝しく計｛はか｝り、火加減｛ひかげん｝を上手｛じょうず｝に調整｛ちょうせい｝して）炊｛た｝く」

いずれの表現｛ひょうげん｝でも、単｛たん｝に「煮る」「塗る」「炊く」ではなく、最終｛さいしゅう｝結果｛けっか｝である「甘い小豆」「白い壁」「おいしいご飯」という結果を満足｛まんぞく｝に得｛う｝るために、括弧｛かっこ｝の中｛なか｝に記載｛きさい｝したような必要｛ひつよう｝な作業｛さぎょう｝を正｛ただ｝しくしかも心｛こころ｝を込｛こ｝めて実施｛じっし｝するということが隠｛かく｝された表現｛ひょうげん｝です。