# Help with this Usage of an Adverb

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I came across this sentence:

電話番号を新しく変えたので認証コードが届きません。

I believe it means "I changed my number to a new one, so I can't receive verification codes."

My question is, how should I understand this use of 新しく変えた? I can't find any resources that talk about using a ～く adverb (or any adverb) in this way.

Is my translation wrong, and it means something more like "newly changed"? As in, the change is new? Or is 新しく somehow acting as a result of 変えた/

I would have said 電話番号に新しいものを変えたので、認証コードが届きません。

Could someone at least provide some example sentences that use adverbs in the same way as above?

Edit: 届けません→届きません

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but 届けません is wrong in the sentence. Where did you get that?

Comment: I guess [this](https://selftaughtjapanese.com/2019/02/06/adverbial-ku%ef%bc%88%e3%80%9c%e3%81%8f%ef%bc%89form-of-japanese-i-adjectives-and-challenges-of-translating-them/) answers your question. Check your relevant parts of your textbook.

Comment: @sundowner Sorry, why is that wrong? I'm reading it as just 丁寧語 negative potential. What should it be?

Comment: I'm not sure to whom the message is directed from whose perspective. 届ける only works as a transitive counterpart of intransitive 届く.

Comment: @sundowner You're saying I can't use the potential of 届く because it's identical to the transitive 届ける? So the only way to say "cannot receive" here would be 届くことができない? (without using a completely different word)

Comment: Yes. I never thought about it, though.  Also note that 届く is literally *to arrive*, not *to receive* (more normally 受け取る). So *cannot receive* is 受け取ることができない (if potential, 受け取れない).

Comment: @charlemagne typically in Japanese, inanimate things are not described with the potential form. The thing performing the action of 届く would be 認証コード, and that's inanimate. But in any case, you said you found the sentence, right? Where did you find it?

Comment: @Leebo I found it on hinative while. I was looking for how to say something similar, found that sentence, and changed the き to a け myself. I still don't understand the use of 新しく though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does 甘く work in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55796/5010) BTW "電話番号**に**新しいもの**を**変えたので" is wrong (it would mean "I changed the new one to a phone number"). 電話番号**を**新しいもの**に**変えた is correct.

Comment: @naruto Wow so it actually is a result thing. That link is perfect, thank you.