# Understanding いい顔に撮れてるじゃないか

Tags: particle-に

([Link to the scene in question](https://www.youtube.com/live/EJcogvuDOSY?feature=share&t=1235))

In the Street Fighter 6 intro, Luke looks at the ID photo on the player character's new dojo membership card. He then says this to the player character:

> うん、いい顔に撮れてるじゃないか

...which is translated as:

> Yeah gotta say, you're photogenic.

What is the role of the に particle here combined with 撮れてる? What I know is that 撮る, especially when written with that Kanji, is related to taking pictures, and I also know that you can say things like ～を写真に撮る to mean something along the lines of "to capture into an image".

Answer (score 1):

I think this に is either:

- に as a role marker (∼ として, *as*, *for*): [に to indicate the role you want something to play?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65432/5010)
- に to mark the result/goal of an action (∼ *as*, *to*, *into*). いい顔 is a noun, but a similar に is commonly used with na-/no-adjectives: [How does 甘く work in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55796/5010)